# Pentaho Kettle don't work after packages update on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-report-designer

The spoon was working normally until an Ubuntu update was run. After updating the `. / spoon.sh` command don't start the application.

I accessed the update log and saw that it only updated things pertaining to postgresql as shown below:

```
Start-Date: 2018-08-17 08:26:45
    Commandline: aptdaemon role = 'role-commit-packages' sender = ': 1.364'
    Upgrade: postgresql-9.3: amd64 (9.3.23-0ubuntu0.14.04, 9.3.24-0ubuntu0.14.04), postgresql-contrib-9.3: amd64 (9.3.23-0ubuntu0.14.04, 9.3.24-0ubuntu0.14.04), postgresql-client-9.3: amd64 (9.3.23-0ubuntu0.14.04, 9.3.24-0ubuntu0.14.04), libpq5: amd64 (9.3.23-0ubuntu0.14.04, 9.3.24-0ubuntu0.14.04)
    End-Date: 2018-08-17 08:27:22
```

I downgraded the Postgresql version, but it did not work. It also excludes Postgresql and I reinstalled, but I was not successful, either.

- Note: In addition to the Spoon, the Pentaho Report Designer also stopped working.

Would you have any idea of ​​the reason?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know how Unix systems work but, check system variables and paths that point to Pentaho related files or Java directories.

Comment: Hi @CristianCurti, thanks for the response. I also don't know the Unix System deeply. I tried to downgrade the postgresql version, but i don't find the version, i also tried to downgrade the Java version, but nothing happens.

I really have no idea about what happens.

Comment: Redirect the spoon output in a file with `./spoon.sh > myfile.log` and publish this myfile.log.

Comment: @AlainD, follow the output:

`OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0`

However, when the spoon was working, this message is displayed in the terminal.

Comment: [SOLVED] Thanks all for the responses. I installed the java JDK **1.8.0_181** version and it work's.

After install, i reboot the OS.

Thanks again.

Comment: Happy for you. Oh, yes, Pentaho 8 requires java 8. It is specified in the release notes that nobody never reads, and the bug does not gives a clear message. As a habit dating of Pentaho 3.7, I install a specific java version on the side of each of my Pentahos. versions.

Comment: Thanks @AlainD. It's a good idea what you do.
What's interested is that i already have the java 8 installed, but after a package update this trouble starts.

Comment: There are a lot of hidden folders like .pentaho, .kettle,... They contain internal variables, references to temp directories and (most important in this case) the license. It is not impossible that a ubuntu upgrade changes changes those hidden directory.